# iOS In App Purchases: Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have in-app purchases set up and I am getting the following error after the `buySubscriptionAction` method:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier: (null)'

This is my code for in-app purchases:

in .h file

```
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
NSArray *validProducts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKProduct *product;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *productID;
```

in .m file

```
-(void) startInAppPurchase {
    self.productID = @"1year";
    [self getProductID];
    [self buySubscriptionAction];
}

// called FIRST
-(void) getProductID {

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please enable in app purchases in your settings" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

// called SECOND
-(void) buySubscriptionAction {

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

After the `buySubscriptionAction` method the app crashes.

I've tried with `self.productID` as `com.companyName.appname.year1` and as `year1` only.  Does anyone know what could be causing this crash and error message?

**Note:**

This method is never called:

```
- (void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    NSLog(@"products: %@",products);

    if (products.count != 0) {
        self.product = products[0];
        productName = self.product.localizedTitle;
        productDescription = self.product.localizedDescription;
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Product Not Found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *prod in products) {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@",prod);
    }
}
```

Therefore, self.products is null in `buySubscriptionAction`.

in .h I have included `<SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>`

Comment: your product ID is apparently null. Set a breakpoint in buySubscriptionAction and inspect self.product. Did you implement the SKProductsRequest delegate methods?

Comment: Yes, it is never called.  Should be after I call `[request start]` right? Also, self.product is null in `buySubscriptionAction`..... So really I guess the question is why isn't that delegate method ever called?

Comment: OK, missing product is your issue. Now set a breakpoint at getProductID start and figure out why your product isn't fetching. You're saying that the delegate method productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: is implemented but never gets called?

Comment: @cdstamper check the note I added to the bottom of the question.  I did an NSLog of the request before I call `[request start]` so I know there is a request being sent.  Do you know why that delegate method isn't being called or how I can debug to figure out why it isn't being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delegate method isn't getting called, despite you assigning delegate = self.

Think about why that could happen. `SKProductsRequest` promises to call a single delegate method when a request completes or times out. Since that's not happening, you can assume 1) system bug 2) `SKProductsRequest` is disappearing somehow.

1) It's never a framework bug.

2) So the `SKProductsRequest` is disappearing. Think through this. Your method ends and you'd like the `SKProductsRequest` instance to *continue* operating.  However, you've now **left method scope** without telling the compiler that you'd like to keep `SKProductsRequest` alive. The system assumes you're finished with the `SKProductsRequest` instance and destroys it.

Your issue is that you've failed to ensure the `SKProductsRequest` instance continues to exist after you've left the method scope.

Create a `strong` property and use it to store the request. This will explicitly tell the compiler not to dispose of the `SKProductsRequest` object until leaving class context. Problem should be solved.

Comment: AHA! So I had a couple issues that I fixed.  1) I made the strong property for the request.  2) I was retrieving the products at the same time as I try to make an `SKPayment` so of course there were no products to make an `SKPayment` on... Thanks for your help!